# Не выводится в представление список в формате JSON ASP.NET

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина. Не отображаются данные, которые получаю в контроллере в формате JSON.

Модель:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("№")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ФИО клиента")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Телефон")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public JsonResult GetCustomersList()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customersList = this.db.Customers.Select(a => new Customer
    {
        CustomerId = a.CustomerId,
        Phone = a.Phone,
        Name = a.Name,
        Orders = a.Orders
    }).ToList();

    return this.Json(customersList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JS:

```
var MyAppUrlSettings = {
    MyUsefulUrl: '@Url.Action("GetCustomersList", "Home")'
};

$.ajax({
    url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function (request) {
        console.log(request);
    },
    success: function (customersList) {
        console.log(typeof customersList, customersList);
        var setData = $("#SetCustomerList");
        setData.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < customersList.length; i++) {
            var data = "<tr class='row_" + customersList[i].CustomersId + "'>" +
                "<td>" + customersList[i].CustomerId + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + customersList[i].Name + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + customersList[i].Phone + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + customersList[i].Phone + "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<a href='#' class='btn btn-warning' onclick='EditCustomerRecord(" +
                customersList[i].CustomerId +
                ")' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>" +
                "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='DeleteCustomerRecord(" +
                customersList[i].CustomerId +
                ")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>" +
                "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            setData.append(data);
            $("#LoadingCustomerStatus").html("");
        }

    }
});
```

Выяснилось, что проблема в:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

```
...
//async: false, - убрать и никогда не писать: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
dataType: 'json',
...
error: function (request) {
    console.log(request);
},
success: function (customersList) {
    console.log(typeof customersList, customersList);
    //customersList = JSON.parse(customersList); - убрать, это уже js объект
    var setData = $("#SetCustomerList");
    setData.empty();
    ...
```

Comment: при прямом обращении к методу GetCustomersList в браузере выскакивает ошибка: System.NotSupportedException: "The entity or complex type 'ZollaTestApp.Models.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: А зачем "прямоe обращениe к методу GetCustomersList"?

Comment: посмотреть выдаются ли json данные, по идее мне в браузере должно выдать список из бд

Comment: Вы вообще в обработчик `success` попадаете?

Comment: как проверить? я не проверял обрабочик сейчас, ранее было без обработчика и список не выводился.

Comment: я добавил строчку с `console.log`

Comment: а где теперь посмотреть что вывелось? отладка-окна-вывод? там только Поток 0x297c завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).

Comment: В браузере - кнопка F12 - "Инструменты разработчика", закладка "Консоль".

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):118

Comment: кхм, кхм, у Вас библиотека jQuery не загружена в страницу, а мы тут копья ломаем :)

Comment: дак как так, в лейауте @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") да и модалки то всплывают, и в дереве jquery есть вместе с другими подгружаемыми библиотеками

Comment: вы правы, косяк в порядке загрузки скриптов. Но теперь при загрузке обрабатывается error: function () { alert("Server access failure!"); }, т.е. не саксесс

Comment: добавьте `console.log` в обработчик `error`, как я показал в ответе

Comment: вообще не понимаю тогда, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: какого контроллера метод `GetCustomersList` и в каком контроллере генерится вью с `$.ajax`?

Comment: все в одном контроллере Home

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77213/discussion-between-e1ement-and-igor).

Comment: попробуйте `IEnumerable<Customer> customersList = this.db.Customers.Select().ToList();`

Comment: решарпер ошибку пишет "ни одна из перегрузок метода Select не принимает 0 аргументов"